# Getting documents from Firestore after network connection gets reset - Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore in my Android app. It's a quiz application where I randomly get documents from Firestore. When the internet connection is good, the app works fine. When the network gets disconnected and then again gets connected, I am unable to read the documents. When I debug, I find that my get() method is not getting executed at all.

```
Iterator iterator = randomIds.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            String documentId = (String) iterator.next();

            DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection(categoryName).document(documentId);
            if (documentReference!=null) {
                documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            System.out.println("Task successful");
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                            questionDetailsObj = new QuestionDetails();
                            questionDetailsObj = document.toObject(QuestionDetails.class);
                            if (questionDetailsObj != null) {
                                System.out.println("Question details: " + questionDetailsObj.getQuestion_text());
                           // Adding the questions to a list
                                questionsList.add(questionDetailsObj);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "get() failed with " + task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    }
```

I want to retrieve 10 documents. Sometimes, few documents are retrieved successfully and for the others I get the exception

```
get() failed with com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: 
Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

I don't understand why would some documents come successfully and some fail to get retrieved. Please help me understand if any code changes are required.

Comment: FYI this will never be false in your code: `if (documentReference!=null)`.  document() will never return null.  A reference is join a pointer, not a guarantee that data exists.

Comment: And bear in mind that being "online" doesn't guarantee that Firestore has an active connection.  It may be in the middle of an exponentially delayed  retry cycle, in which cache non-cached documents may not fetch.